# is there a way to recover variable names in llvm generated code?

Tags: llvm

Is there a way to recover the source code variables in llvm bytecode? I've looked into debug information that llvm provides but I don't think they are stored.

Comment: DebugInfo should contain it for sure.

Comment: @arrowd I only found things like names declared in variable declarations with `-O0`. But for code like `a+b` I'd like to recover the variables being added.

Comment: Variable names *can* be stored, in debug info. That doesn't mean that they *are* stored, that depends on the frontend.

Comment: Do you know which C/C++ frontend generate the most debug info?